# Communicate Unity application via a series of Json

Tags: unity, c#, json

I am working on communicating unity application via a series of Json. Since I am new to JSON, I don't have any idea how that work with Wnity.

Here is my JSON structure

```
{
    "id": “id",
    "payload": {
            “image”: "Image Url”
            "text":"text message"
            "option" : {
               "option1":"1" ,
               "option2": "2"
                }
    }
```

}

Now I have created a button in Unity scene. I have hardcoded the image and text data. When I click on the button the data should get converted into Json and should send JSON data to the server and print a data log message.

I have used this code.Iam getting the output

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using LitJson;
using System.IO;
public class JsonScript : MonoBehaviour {
JsonData json;
void Start()
{
    Data data = new Data();
    data.id = 1;
    data.payload = new Payload() { text = "wwwwwww", image = "hello" };
    //json = JsonMapper.ToJson(data) ;
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
    P (json);
    //      P(json + "\t\n");

 }

// Use this for initialization
void P(string aText)
{
    print (aText +"\n");
}
```

}

```
  [System.Serializable]
 public class Payload
  {
    public string text;
       public string image;
 }

     [System.Serializable]
    public class Data
  {
        public int id;
        public Payload payload;
  }
```

The output is getting displayed in a single line

{"id":1,"payload":{"text":"wwwwwww","image":"hello"}}

But I need the output to be printed as the Json format.I tried giving space.

Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html 
The documentation has very detailed explaination.
In your case the classes/structures (that store data ) should look like:

```
[Serializable]
public class Payload
{
    public string imageUrl;
    public string text;
}

[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public int id;
    public Payload payload;
}
```

Mark them with Serializable attribute so that they can be serialized.
To serialize it , you do:

```
Data data = new Data();
data.id = <any id>;
data.payload = new Payload() { imageUrl = <any url>, text = <any text> };

string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
```

And to convert the json string back into data you do:

```
var data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data >(json);
```

That's it, hope this helps.

---

**Edit 01**: Pretty format JSON 
(in the same documentation as above )

> Controlling the output of ToJson()
>
> ToJson **supports pretty-printing the JSON output**. It is off by default
>   but you can turn it on by passing true as the second parameter.

So i guess all you need to do is just :

```
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data,true);
```

Honestly, I havent tried it yet but I do believe in what the documentation says :D

---

**Edit02** :

```
[Serializable]
public class Option
{
    public int option01;
    public int option02;
}
[Serializable]
public class Payload
{
    public string imageUrl;
    public string text;
}

[Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public int id;
    public Payload payload;
    public Option option;
}

Data data = new Data();
data.id = <any id>;
data.payload = new Payload() { imageUrl = <any url>, text = <any text> };
data.option= new Option() { option01 = 1, option02 = 2 };

string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(data,true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Its working fine.  I have a dout the output is getting displayed as                                                                        {"id":1,"payload":{"text":"wwwwwww","image":"hello"}} in a single line .how can I display the message as the json structure as mentioned in the question

Comment: @user1509674 I think what you are looking for is printing a "beautified" version of the JSON, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178544/how-can-i-beautify-a-json

Comment: @Shautieh : I went through the link you provided,but Newtonsoft.Json is a paid library right.Is there any other library.Here I have used LitJson and SimpleJSON

Comment: @user1509674 The second answer seems good enough: http://www.markdavidrogers.com/json-pretty-printerbeautifier-library-for-net/ . Otherwise I'm not using one so I can't recommend any, but there should be plenty just googling "c# json beautifier"!

Comment: @user1509674 : Hey, I edited my answer, just take a look.

Comment: @s76 :Sir i have a dout,I have edited the json structure.If I need to display the above format how can I do it.I means the option part of it

Comment: I've added it to my answer. The rule is quite simple, just make everything in your structure serializable.